# Algorithm not returning shortest path in python

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, a-star

I have to make an algorithm that finds the shortest path from a graph, similar to a traveling salesman problem, the graph should visit all the nodes an return back the shortest path.
The algorithm worked fine, but as the nodes should only be visited once, I've tried to cater for visited nodes, but my function is returning none.

I have added a visited set to cater for visited nodes, but my algorithm is returning none since then.

Here is my algorithm:

```
# The main function to perform the A* algorithm
def a_star(start, goal, graph):
    # The nodes to be visited, stored as (cost, current, path) tuples
    heap = [(0 + euclidean_distance((start, goal), (goal, goal)), start, [start], 0)]

    # Keep track of visited nodes to avoid revisiting
    visited = set()

    while heap:
        (cost, current, path, weight) = heap.pop(0)
        if len(path) == N:
            return path, weight
        if current in visited:
            continue
        visited.add(current)
        for i, node in enumerate(graph[current]):
            if node > 0 and i not in path:
                heap.append((cost + node + euclidean_distance((i, goal), (goal, goal)), i, path + [i], weight + node))
        heap = sorted(heap, key=lambda x: x[0])

    return None, None
```

Comment: A\* is useless for solving TSP.

Comment: Please add failing small example and debugging information.

Answer (score 0):

Your first bug is that using `pop(0)` on an array does **NOT** make it work like a heap.  Your `cost` is being ignored.  Instead you need to [heapq.heappop()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) to make this an actual A* search.

But the more fundamental bug is in trying to use A* search at all on this problem.  The reason why is that you won't revisit a node if any other path has reached it.  And often another path DOES reach it before the one you want to find.  So you can never find the path that you want.

Here is an example.  Suppose your graph looks like

```
       A
     / | \
start  |  goal
     \ | /
       B
```

Here are the steps:

1. From `start` you add to the queue that you can get to `A` and `B`. Mark `start` as `visited`
2. You look at the path `start - A`, see that `A` is not visited, add to the queue that you can get to `goal`, `B` and `start`. Mark `A` as visited.
3. You look at the path `start - B`, see that `B` is not visited, add to the queue that you can get to `goal`, `A` and `start`. Mark `B` as visited.
4. You look at the path `start - A - goal`, see that `goal` is not visited.  Find that your path is too short.
5. You look at the path `start - B - goal`, see that `goal` is not visited.  Find that your path is too short.
6. You look at the path `start - A - B`, see that `B` IS visited and stop.
7. You look at the path `start - B - A`, see that `A` IS visited and stop.
8. You look at the path `start - A - start`, see that `start` IS visited and stop.
9. You look at the path `start - B - start`, see that `start` IS visited and stop.
10. You give up.

And you see that you abandoned `start - A - B` because `start - B` is shorter.  And likewise abandoned `start - B - A` because `start - A` is shorter.  Which gives you no chance of finding `start - A - B - goal` or `start - B - A - goal`.  (Either of which would have made you happy.)